# Get Substring of a String by Startindex and Endindex

Tags: string, vb.net

I try to extrat `1,2,3` as a String from the String `Data:[1,2,3]`. Doing this with the following Code gives me the `Error Index and length must refer to a location within the string` it looks like I am completely blind but I do not see what is wrong. Could anyone help me?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim name As String = "Data:[1,2,3]"
    Console.Write(name.Substring(6, name.Length - 1))
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Comment: you're looking for `Console.Write(name.Substring(6, 5))`. the latter number is the count not the index.

Comment: Console.Write(Mid(name, 6))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument in `String.Substring` is the length, so the number of characters that should be taken from the first argument's index. You should look for the  brackets instead:

```
Dim startIndex = name.IndexOf("["c)
If startIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim endIndex = name.IndexOf("]"c, startIndex)
    If endIndex >= 0 Then
       startIndex += 1 ' because you dont want to include the  brackets
       Dim data = name.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for, since I need to use it on different string lengths. Good anticipation.